# How i can acces images in request (with dropzone-flask)?

Tags: python, flask, dropzone

I want to upload image with dropzone(flask) and after uploading show page with this image(from request, i don't want to save image on disk like in this example) and name of file. I found example on github https://github.com/greyli/flask-dropzone/blob/master/examples/in-form/app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_dropzone import Dropzone

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.update(
    UPLOADED_PATH=os.path.join(basedir, 'uploads'),
    # Flask-Dropzone config:
    DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPE='image',
    DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE=3,
    DROPZONE_MAX_FILES=1,
    DROPZONE_IN_FORM=True,
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ON_CLICK=True,
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_ACTION='handle_upload',  # URL or endpoint
    DROPZONE_UPLOAD_BTN_ID='submit',
)

dropzone = Dropzone(app)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def handle_upload():
    for key, f in request.files.items():
        if key.startswith('file'):
            print( f.filename)
    return '', 204


@app.route('/form', methods=['POST'])
def handle_form():
    ############################################
    #i want to access request.files.items() there
    #############################################

    title = request.form.get('title')
    description = request.form.get('description')
    return 'file uploaded and form submit<br>title: %s<br> description: %s' % (title, description)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

after uploading images in handle_upload() i can get images from request, but for rendering template in handle_form() i need to save images to disk. i want to send images from handle_upload() to handle_form() (without using global variables)

Comment: why do you not want to save the image to disk? You are going to have to save it somewhere and the file system would seem a natural choice.

Comment: i want to process files with opencv. I don't need file, i need only prediction of neural network

Comment: You may not need to keep the file permanently but you are going to have to store it somehow until you process it with opencv. There are only so many ways you can store data between requests. The filesystem would seem to be the best place to store a file, a database would seem a less good option and as you say, a global variable would be a bad option.

Comment: without dropzone i get image from request and decode from jpeg. and that works. but i want pretty ui and want do same with dropzone

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the image file from request in *handle_form()* if the image was sent in *handle_upload()*. [See Lifetime of Request Context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/reqcontext/)

You have 2 choice:

- Return directly the image and the file name in *handle_upload()* (context still exists)
- Save the image file on the disk